# $R$-module on $V$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Recall the ring of polynomials $R = F[t]$ with coeﬃcients in a ﬁeld $F$.

Fix $T$ in $\mathrm{Hom}_F(V,V)$. Show that there is a unique (left) $R$-module structure on $V$ such that

> $(a + bt, v) = av + bTv,$      for all $a$ and $b$ in $F$.

Hello. I'm having trouble with this homework problem. Particularly, I don't exactly understand the relationship between $t$ and $T$. Could someone please explain to me what this question is asking?

Thanks,
Natasha